# Orbeon - In Wizard Mode, can section navigation be done externally?

Tags: orbeon

Our design includes an external application that allows navigation between a set of forms. Initially we were thinking of using Wizard Mode for navigation between sections. Unfortunately this creates two separate mechanisms for navigation which proves a bit clunky and uses up more screen real estate. We would like to combine the two.

We still would like to navigate the form sections the same way that Wizard Mode does but would like to:

1. Hide the Wizard Mode Table of Contents
2. Navigate sections using an external mechanism

Is there a simple way to do this or is it ugly?

Comment: Hiding the table of contents can be done with CSS, with strong enough rules. How would that external mechanism communicate with Form Runner? Via JavaScript?

Comment: @ebruchez Yes, since section navigation within a form is done client side I think it would have to be JavaScript. I think ideally we would use client side Inter Portlet Communication, but of course that would require modifications to the Proxy Portlet and Form Runner.

Comment: @ebruchez Also, the portlet controlling navigation will be tightly coupled with the Proxy Portlet going around IPC with JavaScript is not a big deal.

Comment: @ebruchez I am rethinking this a bit. It may be simplest to just forget about Wizard Mode and use the default layout. We can then use CSS/JavaScript to hide all but the one section we want to see. The `div` for each section seems to have a consistent ID for example the `div` for `section 1` has `id="section-1-control"`. Wizard Mode auto-focuses to the first field in the section. We wouldn't get that with this option, but that's fine. Is there any reason not to use this method?

Comment: @ebruchez Did you have any thoughts on my last comment? Does it seem OK? Is there a better way?

Comment: You miss things if you show/hide sections with your own CSS, for example the error summary won't open a section for you. So it might show errors and the user won't be able to easily navigate to the section containing the error.

Comment: So what if we added a client-side Wizard API to navigate pages? Would that help?

Comment: @ebruchez We were actually planning to hide the error summary using CSS since we will do validation externally using a rules engine. It sounds like we'd be OK just hiding the sections using CSS. But I think with that we risk briefly showing all sections before that CSS is loaded.

Comment: @ebruchez A client-side API would be preferable rather than relying on Orbeon's naming conventions for the section divs. We would need a way to hide the Table of Contents too. We would need all sections to be hidden on load so that the user wouldn't briefly see all sections. Ideally we would be able to supply a parameter to the proxy portlet via IPC to specify which section is displayed initially, much like my pull request https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/pull/2373 for form selection.

Comment: Hiding the TOC would be easy with CSS no matter what. Now if the parameter identifying the wizard page to show is passed to the server, we would only need a server-side API, not a client-side API I think.

Comment: @ebruchez Right. We would need a server-side API for that. I meant that to be in addition to the client-side API. We might want to initially display section 3, but then navigate to section 2 without a page refresh.

Comment: Got it. So there is another RFE for this: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2383

Comment: @ebruchez Great! Thank, Erik.

Answer (score 0):

you have probably resolved this by now but just thought I'd add that I have successfully disabled the TOC using the following CSS:-

```
.fr-wizard-toc {width:0; height:0; visibility:hidden;}
.fr-wizard-body {width:100% !important; left:0 !important;}
```

Once the TOC is hidden, the main body needs to be re-aligned to the left margin and expanded to its full width. Be sure to use !important, otherwise this rule will be overridden by Orbeon!